# Powershell read in csv columns from large number of files then output to new csv where each file is a new column

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, multiple-columns, powershell-2.0

I have a number of files i want to read a specific column in from each, then output each of those to one new csv file, with each file read in as a new column. I currently have the reading in and outputting to a new file working, but it outputs everything into one column, how do i separate out each files data?

This is what i have currently

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header @("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i") (Get-ChildItem -path C:\Users\xxxxx *.tsv) |
    select g |
    Export-Csv newfile.csv -NoType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feed the output from `Get-ChildItem` as input to `ForEach-Object`, then import/extract/export from each file separately:

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\Users\xxxxx *.tsv |ForEach-Object {
    Import-Csv -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Delimiter "`t" -Header @("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i") |
    Select-Object g |
    Export-Csv ($_.BaseName + '_newfile.csv') -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: getting this error when i run that Import-Csv : You must specify either the -Path or -LiteralPath parameters, but not both.
At line:2 char:10
+     $_ | Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header @("a","b","c","d","e","f" ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Import-Csv], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotSpecifyPathAndLiteralPath,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand

Comment: @JoeP Should be fixed now, try again :)